# How to access variable of thread's constructor in run function?

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads, php-pthread

```
  class Test extends thread {
     function __construct(&$db,$userObj) {  
     $this -> userObj = $userObj;
     print "Original:";
     var_dump($db);
     $this->db = $db;
     print "InThread:";
     var_dump($this->db);      
     // as value of $this->db and db(in constructor) is different I am gettting different values. 
  }
 public function run(){
  $userId = $this->userObj->getUserId();
  $data = $this->db->getData();
 // as value of $this->db and db(in constructor) is different I am getting different values. 
  }

 function getData(&$db,$userObj){
  $thread = new Test($db,$userObj);
  $thread->start();
  }
```

I want to use the value of db in my run function. How to access thread constructor variable via run() without changing $db values.

Answer (score 0):

Objects set as member properties of `Threaded` objects that are not themselves `Threaded` will be automatically serialized on write, and automatically unserialized on read.

When a `Threaded` member property is accessed, `pthreads` needs to prohibit the return of objects created by other `Threads` because of the architecture of PHP (share nothing).

If the property itself is `Threaded` then this is efficiently managed (in PHP7), but you still do not get the same physical object.

This is the reason that `$this->db` and `$db` are different objects.

Trying to pass by reference won't make any difference; `Threaded` objects do not support references to member properties.